# Java indexOf and lastIndexOf return -1?? Please Help

Tags: java

In the following code, I am trying to check if an int (converted to String) contains duplicate digits.

```
public static boolean hasDupes(int n)
  {
    String number = new String();
    number = Integer.toString(n);
    int digit = 0;
    System.out.println(num.indexOf(digit));
    System.out.println(num.lastIndexOf(digit));
    while(digit < 10)
    {
      if(number.indexOf(digit) != number.lastIndexOf(digit))
      {
        return true; 
      }
      digit++;
    }
    //System.out.println(n);
    return false;
  }
```

I put in the `System.out.println` lines because I was unsure as to why my method wasn't working. They always print out '-1'. I dont understand how an index can be -1, and why it isn't working.

Comment: Index -1 means it couldn't be found in the string. As per the documentation...

Comment: your printlns say "num" but your String is called "number".

Comment: I assume there is a typo because you initialize `number` and call the methods on `num`. Oh, and NEVER call the String constructor, it's useless. Just do `String number = Integer.toString(n);` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
number.indexOf(digit)
```

`digit` is an `int`. Passed to `indexOf` it will be used as a character number, so you'll be looking for char 0 (the null character) instead of the ASCII digit `'0'`. Naturally that character isn't in the string, so you get -1.

You're probably thinking of the `indexOf(String)` method. eg

```
var dstr= ""+digit;
if (number.indexOf(dstr) != number.lastIndexOf(dstr))
    return true;
```

Or, if you want to do it with a range of character codes:

```
for (char digit= '0'; digit<='9'; digit++)
    if (number.indexOf(digit) != number.lastIndexOf(digit))
        return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because you're calling indexOf with an int parameter, but it's looking for a character with that unicode value, NOT the string value.  Convert the digit to a String, like so:

```
while(digit < 10)
    {
      String digitString = String.valueOf(digit);
      if(number.indexOf(digitString) != number.lastIndexOf(digitString))
      {
      ...
```